# Make Location definition for UWP app in PCL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I writing UWP app.

I created PCL for UWP project.

It download data for latitude and longtitude (this is weather app). Also I need to define lat and lon for location of smartphone.

Here is my code:

```
public class OpenWeatherViewModel
{
    private const string APPID = "f3c45b5a19426de9ea6ba7eb6c6969d7";
    private List<RootObject> weatherList;

    public List<RootObject> WeatherListList
    {
        get { return weatherList; }
        set { weatherList = value; }
    }

    public OpenWeatherViewModel()
    {
        Data_download();
    }




    public async void Data_download()
    {
        var geoLocator = new Geolocator();
        geoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
        Geoposition pos = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        string latitude = "Latitude: " + pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString();
        string longitude = "Longitude: " + pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString();
        var url = String.Format(
            "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={0}&lon={1}&units=metric&APPID=" + APPID, latitude, longitude);
        var json = await FetchAsync(url);



        List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

        WeatherListList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);
    }

    public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        string jsonString;

        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
```

On this row `Geoposition pos = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();` I have error: `Error CS0012 The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.`

How I can fix this?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of Portable Class Library is helping build cross-platform apps and libs, sharing code between different parts of your app.

When create a PCL in VS 2015, you can specify the types of API for Windows 10, universal app. But here this method is only avaiable for WinRT apps, not traditional Win32 app, I think it's not a good design to put this in a PCL, you can move these code into your UWP app.

Or if you just want to create a library for your UWP app, you can create a `Class Library (Universal Windows)` instead of creating `Class Library (Portable)`:

[image]

You can compare the `References` of these two different PCLs.

Class Library (Portable):

[image]

Class Library (Universal Windows):

[image]

The references in the image above enable the use of UWP apis in your class library.